# Multilayer Perceptron works fine with sigmoid activations, but not with hyperbolic tangent

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, deep-learning

I have written a simple MLP with one single layer. When learning the XOR function using sigmoid activations, the loss reduced consistently. However, if I change the labels of the XOR data from [0, 1] to [-1, 1] and use the tanh activation instead, the loss doesn't reduce. It should still work by simply changing the labels and using tanh, shouldn't it? And if so, where is my implementation going wrong with tanh?

```
import sys

import numpy as np


class DataSet:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.size = len(data)
        self.inputs, self.labels = [], []
        for i in range(len(data)):
            self.inputs.append(data[i][0])
            self.labels.append(data[i][1])
        try:
            self.numInputs = len(self.inputs[0])
        except TypeError:
            self.numInputs = 1
        try:
            self.numOutputs = len(self.labels[0])
        except TypeError:
            self.numOutputs = 1


class MLP:

    def __init__(self, numInputs, numHidden, numOutputs, activationFunction):
        # MLP architecture sizes
        self.numInputs = numInputs
        self.numHidden = numHidden
        self.numOutputs = numOutputs
        self.activationFunction = activationFunction.lower()

        # MLP weights
        self.IH_weights = np.random.rand(numInputs, numHidden)      # Input -> Hidden
        self.HO_weights = np.random.rand(numHidden, numOutputs)     # Hidden -> Output

        # Gradients corresponding to weight matrices computed during backprop
        self.IH_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.IH_weights)
        self.HO_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.HO_weights)

        # Input, hidden and output neuron values
        self.I = np.zeros(numInputs)    # Inputs
        self.L = np.zeros(numOutputs)   # Labels
        self.H = np.zeros(numHidden)    # Hidden
        self.O = np.zeros(numOutputs)   # Output

    # ADD BIAS FOR RELU ########################################################
    # ADD SOFTMAX ##############################################################
    def activation(self, x, derivative=False):
        if self.activationFunction == 'sigmoid':
            if derivative:
                return x * (1 - x)
            return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

        if self.activationFunction == 'tanh':
            if derivative:
                return 1. - np.tanh(x) ** 2
            return np.tanh(x)

        # if self.activationFunction == 'softmax':
        #     if derivative:
        #         return ########
        #     return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x))

        if self.activationFunction == 'relu':
            if derivative:
                return (x > 0).astype(float)
            return np.maximum(0, x)

        print("ERROR: Activation function not found.")
        sys.exit()

    def forward(self, inputs):
        # Ensure that inputs is a list
        try:
            len(inputs)
        except TypeError:
            inputs = [inputs]

        self.I = np.array(inputs).reshape(1, self.numInputs)
        self.H = self.I.dot(self.IH_weights)
        self.H = self.activation(self.H)
        self.O = self.H.dot(self.HO_weights)
        self.O = self.activation(self.O)
        return self.O, self.L

    def backwards(self, labels):
        # Ensure that labels is a list
        try:
            len(labels)
        except TypeError:
            labels = [labels]

        self.L = np.array(labels)
        self.O_error = self.L - self.O
        self.O_delta = self.O_error * self.activation(self.O, derivative=True)

        self.H_error = self.O_delta.dot(self.HO_weights.T)
        self.H_delta = self.H_error * self.activation(self.H, derivative=True)

        self.IH_gradients += self.I.T.dot(self.H_delta)
        self.HO_gradients += self.H.T.dot(self.O_delta)

        return np.sum(self.O_error ** 2)

    def updateWeights(self, learningRate):
        self.IH_weights += self.IH_gradients
        self.HO_weights += self.HO_gradients
        self.IH_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.IH_weights)
        self.HO_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.HO_weights)

# data = DataSet([
#     [[0, 0], 0],
#     [[0, 1], 1],
#     [[1, 0], 1],
#     [[1, 1], 0]
# ])
#
# mlp = MLP(data.numInputs, 20, data.numOutputs, 'sigmoid')

data = DataSet([
    [[0, 0], -1],
    [[0, 1], 1],
    [[1, 0], 1],
    [[1, 1], -1]
])

mlp = MLP(data.numInputs, 20, data.numOutputs, 'tanh')

numEpochs = 10000
learningRate = 0.01

losses = []
for epoch in range(numEpochs):
    errors = []
    correct = []
    for i in range(data.size):
        mlp.forward(data.inputs[i])
        errors.append(mlp.backwards(data.labels[i]))
    mlp.updateWeights(learningRate)
    epochLoss = np.mean(errors)
    losses.append(epochLoss)
    if epoch % 100 == 0 or epoch == numEpochs - 1:
        print("EPOCH:", epoch)
        print("LOSS: ", epochLoss, "\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for derivatives is erroneous.

You don't calculate derivatives evaluated at input, but on output (for example you take $x(1-x)$ for sigmoid derivative, but it's actually $\sigma(x) (1 - \sigma(x))$.

Because of that your evaluation of $tanh'(x)$ is wrong, in your implementation it should be ($1 - x^2$).

It seems to be a good idea though to leave this one, fix sigmoid derivative instead, and actually evaluate derivatives right.

Comment: I have since realised this. I implemented a working MLP using numpy, as shown here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754939/multilayer-perceptron-works-fine-with-sigmoid-activations-but-not-with-hyperbol/49758402?noredirect=1#comment86535759_49758402), and am now removing this numpy dependency again.